# The count of functions from $X$ to $Y$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $X$ be a set with $N$ elements, and $Y$ a set with $M$ elements. What is the count of possible functions from $X$ to $Y$?

If answer is $M^N$, then why can't it be $N \times M$? That is, why not count for each  $x \in X$, the possible mappings from $x$ to each $y\in Y$?

Comment: That's exactly what you do. For each $x \in X$, there are $M$ possibilities for $f(x)$. So you make $N$ choices, each of which is a choice from one of $M$ possibilities...

Comment: So, for each $x$ in $X$, you have $M$ possibilities. And you have to choose, from among $M$ possibilities, $N$ times. That means that you are choosing $M$, and you are doing so $N$ times. That's $M^N$, not $MN$. (If you have three choices, and you need to make the three choices four times, you have $81$ ways of doing it, not $12$).

Comment: Let $Y=\{a,b,c,\dots,z\}$, and let $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. There are just as many functions from $X$ to $Y$ as there are $5$-letter "words" over our alphabet.

Comment: Funny remark for someone named « André... »

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say you need to determine what you will drink with your meals at home tomorrow. There are two meals, `breakfast` and `dinner`. And you have three options of drink for each meal:  `milk`, `water`, and `beer`.

Now, this is the same as having a function

$f\colon\{$ `breakfast`, `dinner`$\}\to\{$  `milk`, `water`, `beer`$\}$.

How many different combinations of drinks can you have? It's more than $2\times 3=6$ combinations; it's $3^2=9$ combinations:

1. Milk at both breakfast and dinner;
2. Milk at breakfast, water at dinner;
3. Milk at breakfast, beer at dinner;
4. Water at breakfast, milk at dinner;
5. Water at both breakfast and dinner;
6. Water at breakfast, beer at dinner;
7. Beer at breakfast, milk at dinner;
8. Beer at breakfast, water at dinner;
9. Beer at both breakfast and dinner.

As you see: three choices for what to do for breakfast, **and** three choices for what to do at dinner, for  a total of $3\times 3 = 3^2$ possible outcomes.

If you had to plan for $N$ different meals, and you had $M$ choices for each meal? $M$ possible choices for the first, $M$ possible choices for the second, and so on. In the end, do you have $N\times M$, or do you have $M^N$?

Comment: I see my mistake. I was just counting the possible mappings, and not the functions themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate the elements of $X$, $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n\}$.  For $f(x_1)$ you have a choice of $M$ elements.  The same applies to $f(x_2)$.  Continue in this fashion $M$ times.  As a result you have $M^N$ elements.